# scraping web data using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a code for scraping data from the imdb top 250 web page. The code that I have written follows below. The code works and gives me my intended results. But the problem I am facing lies in the number of results the code is returning. When I use it on my laptop, it produces 23 results, the 1st 23 movies as listed by imdb. But when I run from one of my friend's, it produces proper 250 results. Why does this happen? What should be done in order to avoid this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO

try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except:
    import pickle

url = 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/top'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

movies = soup.select('td.titleColumn')
links = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('td.titleColumn a')]
crew = [a.attrs.get('title') for a in soup.select('td.titleColumn a')]
ratings = [b.attrs.get('data-value') for b in soup.select('td.titleColumn span[name=ir]')]
votes = [b.attrs.get('data-value') for b in soup.select('td.ratingColumn strong')]

imdb = []

print(len(movies))

for index in range(0, len(movies)):
    data = {"movie": movies[index].get_text(),
            "link": links[index],
            "starCast": crew[index],
            "rating": ratings[index],
            "vote": votes[index]}
    imdb.append(data)

print(imdb)


Test Run from my laptop result :
['9.21', '9.176', '9.015', '8.935', '8.914', '8.903', '8.892', '8.889', '8.877', '8.817', '8.786', '8.76', '8.737', '8.733', '8.716', '8.703', '8.7', '8.69', '8.69', '8.678', '8.658', '8.629', '8.619']
23
```

Comment: Interesting - I get 250 results when I run it.  Maybe check which version of python and BeautifulSoup you're using?  Then break down the code - inspect `response.text` to see exactly what it contains in each case, to see if the problem is with the request or with the parser.

Comment: @trvrm I've tried several parsers - the same result - 250.

Comment: Thanks.. I have used the exact same software and package versions in both the systems. The python version is 2.7.6.. and for BeautifulSoup I used `pip install` method.. and yes, the `response.text` stored in `soup` contains the 1st 23 entries in the problem case.

Comment: I also receive all 250 results. Are you receiving a complete HTML document containing the 23 entries? Does the document end with a </html> tag, or does it look truncated? Is `response.status_code` 200? Are you using a proxy (and your friend is not).

Comment: Also, which version of `requests` are you using?

Comment: The interesting thing, i am from germany, and i get the german translated versions of the movies, when i visit the page via my firefox browser it's english O_o

Comment: requests version is 2.4.1,
response.status_code is 200,
and the document ends with an </html> tag but contains 23 entries

Comment: @mhawke We both are using same proxy settings to connect to the internet..

Comment: Both German and English result in 250 results for me with requests-2.4.1. I set `Accept-Language : de` to get the page with German movie titles. However, I don't think that requests automatically sets that header, so I am puzzled that you get the German version with requests using the posted code. The English version when using firefox is probably because you haven't configured language preferences, so it defaults to English.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a pretty old question, but I liked the idea enough to get the code working better. It now makes more individual data available by variables. I fixed it up for myself, but thought I'd share here in hopes that it could help someone else.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

# Download IMDB's Top 250 data
url = 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/top'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

movies = soup.select('td.titleColumn')
links = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('td.titleColumn a')]
crew = [a.attrs.get('title') for a in soup.select('td.titleColumn a')]
ratings = [b.attrs.get('data-value') for b in soup.select('td.posterColumn span[name=ir]')]
votes = [b.attrs.get('data-value') for b in soup.select('td.ratingColumn strong')]

imdb = []

# Store each item into dictionary (data), then put those into a list (imdb)
for index in range(0, len(movies)):
    # Seperate movie into: 'place', 'title', 'year'
    # Instead of "2.       The Godfather        (1972)"
    movie_string = movies[index].get_text()
    movie = (' '.join(movie_string.split()).replace('.', ''))
    movie_title = movie[len(str(index))+1:-7]
    year = re.search('\((.*?)\)', movie_string).group(1)
    place = movie[:len(str(index))-(len(movie))]
    data = {"movie_title": movie_title,
            "year": year,
            "place": place,
            "star_cast": crew[index],
            "rating": ratings[index],
            "vote": votes[index],
            "link": links[index]}
    imdb.append(data)

# Print out some info
for item in imdb:
    print(item['place'], '-', item['movie_title'], '('+item['year']+') -', 'Starring:', item['star_cast'])
```